# Flutter PageView page index not persisting when pressing back button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a PageView within my `home.dart` file and would like to have the selected index persist whenever a user navigates back to the `home.dart` file the back button from another page. At the moment, the first page index is the `ImageFeedPage`. If someone were to go to the `ChatPage`, open one of the conversations, and then press the back button, they'll be taken back to the first index which is `ImageFeedPage`, instead of the `ChatPage`.

Any thoughts on how I can correct this so that the selected index, when navigated back to, is still selected?

home.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  PageController pageController;
  int pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  onPageChanged(int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex != 1 && pageIndex != 2) {
      setState(() {
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
      });
    }
  }

  onTap(int pageIndex, User user) {
    if (pageIndex == 1) {
      SearchPage.show(context);
    } else if (pageIndex == 2) {
      AddProductPage.show(context);
    } else {
      pageController.jumpToPage(pageIndex);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ImageFeedPage(),
          new Container(),
          new Container(),
          ClosetPage(),
          ChatPage(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: (pageIndex) => onTap(pageIndex, user),
        activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        items: _buildMenuItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

chatPage.dart

```
class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  final Widget pageTitle = Text('Active Chats');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        // Need to use CustomAppBar
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: new Color(0xfff8faf8),
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 1.0,
          title: pageTitle,
          bottom: new CustomTabBar(
            tabs: <Tab>[
              new Tab(text: 'As Buyer'),
              new Tab(text: 'As Seller'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        drawer: Sidebar(),
        body: _buildTabView(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTabView(context) {
    return new TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text(
            'John',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            return MessagesPage.show(context); <--- Goes to the message page, but pressing back (once opened) takes you to the first index of the PageView, not the ChatPage
          },
        ),
        ChatList(
          messageType: 'seller',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing you can do is store the index in shared preferences in `onPageChange` (or similar name) and check and assign that value when you open the page view page or whatever.

Comment: @Blasanka would you mind providing some code as an example? Not too sure if I follow what you mean. Thanks for your response.

Comment: In my app I used BlocBuilder and it automatically done that for me, try this tutorial to understand how to use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQMfaQeCL6M&t=726s, it will NOT show you how to persist the index but implementing it into your UI is enough to persist it